Question to a solution to an invariance problem from Arthur Engel's book
I have a question with the answer Engel provides to the following problem:
Three integers $a, b, c$ are written on a blackboard. Then one of the integers is erased and replaced by the sum of the other two diminished by $1$. This operation is repeated many times with the final result $17, 1967, 1983$
Could the initial numbers be (a) $2,2, 2$ (b) $3, 3, 3$?
The solution Arthur provides is the following:
If, after some step, we get $(a, b, c)$ with $a \leq b \leq c$, then $c = a + b − 1$, and a backward step yields the triple $(a, b, b − a + 1)$. Thus, we can retrace the last state $(17, 1967, 1983)$ uniquely until the next to last step: $(17, 1967, 1983) ← (17, 1967, 1951) ← (17, 1935, 1951) ← · · · ← (17, 15, 31) ← (17, 15, 3) ← (13, 15, 3) ← · · · ← (5, 7, 3) ← (5, 3, 3)$.
The preceding triple should be $(1, 3, 3)$ containing 1, which is impossible. Thus the triple $(5, 3, 3)$ is generated at the first step. We can get from $(3, 3, 3)$ to (5, 3, 3) in one step, but not from $(2, 2, 2)$.
My main question with this solution is how is that one can take a backward step on this algorithm? One step consists in deleting one number and replacing it with the sum of the other two minus one, meaning that for example if we apply the step to $20,2,2$ and $2,2,2$, substituting $20$ and $2$ respectively, then we clearly get the same triple $3,2,2$. So how is that we can "uniquely" take a step back?
Is this solution wrong or what am I missing?
Also I would like to ask how can I solve $b)$ from this problem without this solution? I was able to work another solution for $a)$ because it's not possible to reach the desired state, but from the sequence the book provides, it looks that we can reach the desired solution from $b)$, so how could one arrive at the correct answer in that case?

The information about the deleted number is not completely lost. The point is that if all integers are positive, the after carrying out the substitution step, the new number is the largest one. This is how we know that in the last step $c$ was replaced. But also, applying the same reasoning again, in the step before that, $b$ must have been the new number, so that you habe $b=a+$ old $c-1$. That's where the expression old $c=b-a+1$ comes from.
The only time when this reasoning doesn't work is when the previous tripple was the initial one. Note also, that we can skip steps that replace the same number twice, so Engel implicitly concatenates those.

 Explanation given by the Author is clearly wrong. Whether the Answer given is right or wrong is a "Different" matter. 
Standing corrected , I would like to reword myself.
Explanation given by the Author is clearly incomplete , glossing over some things. Eventually , the Answer given there is indeed right , though I have some simpler ways.

There are multiple things glossed over here. I will highlight just 2 Issues.
(1) Consider $(5,7,3)$. It might have come from $(5,x,3)$ , where we can erase $x$ & write $5+3-1=7$.
There is no way to know what the $x$ was !
That Information is lost forever , generally.
Then we can not know where $(5,x,3)$ came from.
Eg $x=10$ will come from something , $x=7$ will come from itself , $x=3$ will come from itself , $x=4$ could be Initial value , Etc ...
Yet , out of all the various ways to get $(5,7,3)$ , only some (or even only one) are not Initial values. This Intermediate triplet value will allow us to go even further back.
The Intermediate triplet value $(a,b,c)$ which Arthur talks about is where the new latest element $c$ is consistent with $c=a+b-1$ , otherwise that triplet must be Initial value.
That is where the "unique" value comes from , which is what OP is asking about.
(2)  Not sure why the Author says triple with $1$ is impossible.
Consider Initial value $(1,20,30)$ which can give $(1,20,20)$ or $(1,30,30)$ : these two triples contain $1$ , hence it is not impossible.
Why Arthur says it is impossible ? Arthur is glossing over the thinking that we are trying to get $2$ or $3$ , not $1$. In that sense , we do not want to go to $1$.

A little alternate thinking
Starting with $(2,2,2)$ , when we erase-write once , we get $(2,2,3) \equiv (EVEN,EVEN,ODD)$
Now onwards , there is no change to that $(EVEN,EVEN,ODD)$ , no natter which element we erase-write. Where-as , the target is $(17,1967,1983) \equiv (ODD,ODD,ODD)$ , hence we can never generate it. Hence $(2,2,2)$ is eliminated.
Thus $(3,3,3)$ is the Potential Answer.

Bonus : Changing $(17,1967,1983)$ [ where $(3,3,3)$ was the Potential Initial value ] to $(19,1967,1983)$ , it is easy to check that we can not generate that with either !
Starting with $(3,3,3)$ , we will get $3,3,5 \equiv (3,3,1) \mod 4$
Now onwards , there is no change to that $\mod 4$ value. Where-as the new target $(19,1967,1983) \equiv (3,3,3)$ hence we can never generate it.
This thinking is not useful with $(17,1967,1983)$ , where it might require some tweaks , like $\mod 6$ or $\mod 12$ what-ever.

Hmm , I agree , I too did not claim that the answer given by Arthur was wrong. I only claimed that the "Explanation" given was wrong. In hindsight , I think , better wording on my part would have been "Author is glossing over some things" , @Sahaj , in other words , "Explanation is incomplete".

I reworded things a little , @Sahaj , thank you for engaging with me over this matter !
